# Group Edition - API is not enabled/ ForcePad App

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I have a Group Edition account. I downloaded the ForcePad app from App Store (it has been pulled down now but was available till some time back earlier) and it works perfectly on my org. However, if I build it from source (from the Github repo) and try to run it, I get the "API is not enabled" error on login. FWIW, I created a Connected App with full permissions on my org and I changed the consumer key and secret values in ForcePad app source code while building it.

A) I can't see the option to enable API on my org. Is it even possible to have API enabled on Group edition org?
B) If yes, then how?
C) If not, how does the ForcePad app work on my org - from the code, I can see it uses API calls.

I've been pulling my hair off trying to find how the App Store build of ForcePad works on my Group Edition org but why it prompts for API not enabled when I build it from source. Any expert guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Certain app developers can get API access to orgs without API enabled. I suspect that ForcePad had that ability, but when you build it yourself, you don't have the right codes anymore to get API access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote ForcePad.

Check out [item 3 under the getting started section](https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ForcePad#getting-started):

> (Optional) ForcePad connects to environments that are not otherwise
>   API-enabled, like GE and PE orgs, by using a partner token. If you
>   have a Salesforce partner token, paste it into `RootViewController.h`
>   under `PartnerTokenId`.

That said, getting a partner token is a little trickier! You'd be best off checking with your account rep.